# Why can't I get the followed users of the current user in my Django application?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using the standard `auth.User` model for the User objects, and my `Follow` object model is defined as follows:

```
class Follow(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='followers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False
    )
    following = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='following',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False
    )
```

The serializer I am using is as follows:

```
class PublicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'username')
```

And my view is as follows:

```
class FollowingView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.following.all()
```

This is returning an empty result set, for some reason that I cannot understand. However, if I use the following code for the view, it DOES return the correct queryset:

```
class FollowingView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        follows = Follow.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('following_id', flat=True)
        return User.objects.filter(id__in=follows)
```

So why can't I get the correct queryset by using `self.request.user.following.all()`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is that, this:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=follows)
```

Is using a Django [Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) in order to obtain the list of available users from the database and then filtering it down to a subset of the users.

Whereas this:

```
self.request.user.following.all()
```

Is getting it's information from the request.  So, unless you were passing the complete dataset in with your request you would never get what you were expecting here.

Comment: OK that makes sense. But if I try retrieving the user as follows, I still get an empty result set: `user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
return user.following.all()`